# Compare two dates and populate value to new column

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to modify FormMule by adding 3 new columns to my sheet named: Details

Seems easy enough as I need to just add columns to my Details sheet - and compare the values.

The columns are as follows:

- F - Date - formatted as mm/dd/yyyy
- G - Date - formatted as mm/dd/yyyy
- M - Today's Date - called with =GoogleClock() and formatted as mm/dd/yyyy

Here are my two scenarios:

1. Compare date of F to date of M.  If F is the same date as or later/after than M - populate cell O in the same row with YES. If not, populate cell O with NO
2. Compare date of G to date of M. If G is the same date as or later/after than M - populate cell N in same row with YES, if not, populate cell with NO.

Can anyone help?  I've done some basic scripting but this is too advanced for me right now. I know it's just basic "Ifs" but could use some guidance so I can learn how to execute items like this in the future.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you need to do this with Google Apps Script, or whether native spreadsheet formulae would do? The latter would be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Adam - good question - I thought the only way to get this to work would be with script itself, but if there's a way to do this in the sheet itself, that's cool too - I just figured I'd have to script up something to make the values populate.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the data starts in row 1. In O1 you can enter:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(F:F*M:M;IF(F:F>=INT(M:M);"YES";"NO");IFERROR(1/0)))`

and in N1:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(G:G*M:M;IF(G:G>=INT(M:M);"YES";"NO");IFERROR(1/0)))`

These are *array formulae* that will automatically populate down the columns as new data is added. If your data actually starts in row 2 (say you had one header row), enter the formulae in row 2 and change the references to F2:F, M2:M etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, AdamL - I just got frozen in Script trying to find a way to do this and didn't even consider the spreadsheet formula option. Awesome.